# https request on port 8443 through Fastify

Tags: node.js, ssl, fastify

I have setup [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) on my wordpress site which is hosted on dreamhost.  I would like to send https request to port 8443 where Fastify is listening. But when I do this `curl -k -v https://example.com:8443` , I get error

`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

when I test http , it works fine and I get the response back on running curl command

To debug this , I run

`openssl s_client -connect example.com:8443` and I get this result:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
121844440805824:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 322 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

relevant part from Fastify setup is

```
const fastify = require('fastify')(
      { logger: true},
      { 
      https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'../../ssl/mykey.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'../../ssl/mycert.cert')),         
              }
     }
```

key and cert are the values from my dreamhost account . I copied the values on server and provided them to fastify

What is missing in this setup? How do I get response back on an https request on port 8443 , where Fastify is listening

Comment: Does it solve https://superuser.com/questions/1754642/ssl-error-wrong-version-number ?

Comment: @Manuel Spigolon
  Thanks. It does not solve but it gives an idea of what else could be missing as `wrong version number` error can be misleading . so how can I capture packet information and provide here , so some one can take a look. Something like this `tcpdump -i any -s0 -w 8443.pcap port 8443` ?  Or can I possibly  do something else to provide more information.